# Getting the center entry of substring_index

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query where I'm calling SUBSTRING_INDEX on a comma delimited string. In all cases the string has two commas. Is there any way to get at the center element only? That is to say, besides doing something like this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(foo, ',', 2), ',', -1)
```

Comment: Nice question but AFAIK you have to play with string functions as you already done to achieve your goal. Curious to see if someone contradicts myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a regular expression substitution with MySQL but you can take a look at those third party libs for MySQL:

https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp